# Under which possible conditions is measuring with an multimeter a danger to life ?

Tags: current-measurement, safety, multimeter, voltage-measurement

My knowledge of electrics is very limited, I am planning to buy a Multimeter, but I am confused when it comes to safety. I do not really know what is a danger to life when measuring a circuit with a multimeter. Is it the voltage, current, resistor, capacity, frequenz a combination of some of this or other factors. Could you please explain common conditions in working with an multimeter and when it is safe and when not.

Comment: I would expect that these days, any legitimate multimeter will have a CE mark (even if on sale outside the EU) and therefore the product documentation should be able to give a full answer.

Comment: If you are SERIOUS the fuse MUST be HRC (high rupture capacity) and the PCB and other circuitry designed to not bypass a blown fuse when the fuse blows. eg home mains circuits can have fusing currents of over 500A - a fuse may blow elsewhere but sometimes the meter will be the breaking point. If your eg 10A fuse is not able to stopt 50-100-200-400- ... A from flowing in an arc where the fuse was you may die. People have. || On DC circuits arcs can form and hold at amazingly low voltages. I have a 30V loaded 250 Watt PV panel and with due care & skill you could weld using that panel. ....

Comment: .... Murphy has great skill - you don't want to let him weld with the inside of your meter. || SO: Rated for mains or highest likely operation. Able to break possible max fault currents AC & DC. || Probes rated for voltages used. | No exposed internal parts during testing.

Comment: You can't rely on just the CE mark.  Anyone can print that on their meters. If you are really concerned with safety and expect to use the meter in dangerous conditions, then purchase from a reputable manufacturer and expect to pay for that safety.

Comment: The biggest danger from a multimeter is stabbing yourself with the pointy probes.

Comment: Know what you are trying to read (at least approximately) and the limits of your meter.  With a multimeter, read ohms and capacitance on UNPOWERED circuits only.  Don't use a meter to measure completely unknown live quantities such as current or voltage.  I've seen what happens even to high quality meters when someone hooks them up to 4160 VAC... not pretty.

Comment: @Andyaka maybe it should but it won't. At best it will give the technical information needed but will be inpenatrable to those not already in the know. At worst it won't even do that.

Answer (score 5):

Some general points- of course you should always follow the meter and test probe manufacturer's recommendations.

There is danger from electrocution and from release of high energy (shrapnel, molten metal, vapor) in case of a short. Arc flash is a particular type of high energy fault that can cause fatal injuries, A lesser danger of injury (death is less likely) is from high high current causing burn injuries, which can occur even at low voltage. Some cheap meters have no fuse at all in the high current range and putting the probes across a hefty battery or high current supply will melt or blow the test leads off. Others have a fuse but with woefully inadequate interrupting capacity.

In all cases using a multimeter with **at least** the minimum safety category for the situation will reduce the risk. A good summary of the categories is in [this](http://www.testequipmentdepot.com/application-notes/pdf/safety/abcs-of-multimeter-safety_an.PDF) Fluke publication- ABCs of Multimeter Safety.

I would recommend CAT III for most mains measurement situations.

[Here](http://m.ecmweb.com/arc-flash/case-deadly-arc-flash) is an analysis of an incident that killed two people as a result of using cheap multimeter.

Comment: That analysis is why I am sticking to learning micro electronics!

Comment: Another scary short-circuit phenomenon is shorting a lead-acid battery, where the high temperatures caused by the high current boil the liquid, bursting the cells, spraying hot acid everywhere. And since the person who caused the short is probably standing right next to it, well...

Answer (score 4):

I'll skip the fun stuff, like measuring the voltage of a lightning bolt by standing in the middle of a thunderstorm with one DMM probe stuck in the ground while holding the other above your head.

There are two basic areas to be careful of.

First, measuring high voltage (basically, 110 volts or greater). You've got to be careful that you don't inadvertently complete a circuit. This means being careful not to let your fingers touch the metal probe ends, or try it while wet, or get careless about what you touch. A useful technique, if you are worried, is to keep one hand in your pocket. That is, you clip the DMM ground probe to a handy ground point, then use one hand to make the probe connection to the point of interest, while keeping the other hand in your pocket. The very worst thing you can do is to make contact with two voltage sources with both hands - the current path from one hand to another will include your heart, and this is technically known as A Bad Thing.  Another thing to consider is to make sure that your contact points are mechanically stable. Do not, under any circumstances, try to use a DMM on a point which is not held firmly in place, such as the end of a wire which is hanging freely.

For voltages of, let's say, 24 volts or less, the above concerns are simply not much of a problem as long as you're not doing it while immersed in water. With dry hands, 24 volts may give you tingle, but nothing more, and lower voltages, such as 5 volts simply won't produce any sensation at all. Under these conditions, you need to worry more about accidentally short-circuiting two adjacent conductors with the metal end of the probe. This can happen, for instance, if your hand slips, or if you have the probe touching one point and turn away (for instance to look at the DMM face), and change the angle of the probe so that it makes contact with two points and short circuits them. This is most likely to just damage the circuit, but if the voltage being shorted can produce currents of many amps you may get spatters of hot metal being thrown off.

Comment: I would say the most common danger is using ohm mode and sticking it across line voltage or other inadvertent measurement cause fault. Amp mode in parallel, etc. Best case you burn a fuse in the dmm

Comment: @crasic - Although that will certainly damage the DMM, the OP specifically asked "I do not really know what is a danger to life", so I focused on the things that can damage health, rather than equipment.

Comment: Fluke meters put a lightning bolt on their display for anything beyond 30V, so that's my threshold for "high voltage". There's plenty of stuff in the land between 24V and 110V. ±15 Vdc analog rails, 48 Vdc telecom systems, 90 Vdc neon lamps...

Answer (score 0):

One risk is electric shocks.

It's difficult to pin down exactly what point a supply becomes hazardous because it depends on many factors but the general rule of thumb is that supplies below 50V or so are safe enough under normal conditions.

Sticking probes into bits of live metal carries a risk that you will end up touching live metal. How serious that risk is depends on the type of probe you are using, what you are using it to probe and how careful you are.

If one probe is touching an object that is live at a dangerous voltage then you should treat the other probe as also being live.

---

The other side of the safety equation is energy related risks. Something goes wrong during measurement that results in very high current flow. Maybe a spike in the supply flashed over the meter. Maybe the user plugged the test leads into the wrong sockets.

Whatever the cause of the high current event the level of danger depends very much on the type of supply. Industrial and commercial distribution tends to be especially bad for this. In the worst case the energy released as an arc flash can be enough to kill.

Test gear is rated into "categories" depending on the environment in which it will be used. Another answer linked a document from fluke titled "the ABCs of mulitimeter safety which convers this pretty well" but basically you want at least CAT II for working on mains supplies inside portable equippment, CAT III for work on most wiring inside buldings and CAT IV for outdoor work and work on the main service intake.

Be careful of CE marks, they can be self-certified and there is no central tracking. So unscrupulous vendors can and will slap them on virtually anything. I would avoid no-name meters for working on anything hazardous regardless of what measurement category the lables on them claim.

Comment: Re: 50V, I like Fluke's 30V number better. (That being the point where they turn on the lightning bolt warning indicator on the display.) I say this as one who has received a few -48V [ring voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_(telephony)) shocks in my life. They definitely get your attention.